# Is there a regex that can search in a group of lines and replace one line within that group and keep the other words there

Tags: regex, file, sublimetext, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

So for example if I have something like:

```
<House \>
 windows
 walls
<\House>
```

and I want to remove lets say walls how do I do that with regex or is there a better option than regex?

So I need it to look like:

```
<House \>
 windows
<\House>
```

So how would I approach this with regex?

Comment: your xml is not well formed. if it was typo.... vim has `cit` ;-)

Comment: This is not xml, <Building /> is a line or group of lines I should say in a file representing a root directory.

Comment: Which language? Are lookarounds supported?

Comment: regex has lookarounds

Comment: Yes I get that, but not all languages support them. Lookbehinds are not allowed in javascript.

Comment: Gotcha, so yeah what I'm trying to do is do a simple find and replace in sublime text editor using a regex expression.

Comment: In that case I believe lookarounds are supported for sublime. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?s)(?<=<Building \/>).*(?=<\/Building>)` Will capture only what is between your two building tags.

`(?s)` allows `.` to match newline characters

`(?<=<Building \/>)` means your content should follow a block of text matching `<Building />`

`.*` is your content

`(?=<\/Building>)` just means that your content should be followed by `</Building>`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EDKyKZ/10)

If you want to trim all that ugly white space, you could always use [this pattern (`(?s)(?<=<Building \/>)\s*(.*)\s*?(?=<\/Building>)`)](https://regex101.com/r/EDKyKZ/11) and refer to capture group 1.

Comment: @W.Smith since you posted a new question with updated requirements, [Here](https://regex101.com/r/EDKyKZ/12) is the solution to your new problem. Please refrain from asking the same question twice.

Comment: Will do, Thanks again I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
Find: (<Building />\s+)floor(\s+</Building>)
Replace: \1corner\2
```